# Tensorflow serving from s3 path is not working - Could not find base path s3://bucketname

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-s3, tensorflow-serving

Loading model from s3 is not working for me. As per #615 I compiled the server using:

```
bazel build -s -c opt --define with_s3_support=true //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```

and now when I run it using

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/tensorflow_model_server --model_base_path=s3://bucketname/
```

I'm getting

> FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error: Could not find base path s3://bucketname/ for servable default

Any tips on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`s3://bucketname/` isn't resolvable unless you have the AWS SDK installed on that machine.

A much better approach would be to use the URL of the model on S3. If you're going to do that, you have to either make the bucket public, in which everyone will be able to access it, or you have to create a bucket policy which allows access from the server's IP.

If you're hosting your server on AWS, you can also launch it with an IAM role and give it S3FullAccess. This is best for any sort of production environment because you don't have to store API Keys in your source code.